# How to read date_time_set as current time in php?

Tags: php, date, datetime, date-formatting

How to read `date_time_set` as current time in php? it means when i run after 5 min it time should be `3:10`

```
$date=date_create("2018-09-26");
date_time_set($date,3,5);
echo date_format($date,'y-m-d H:i:s')."\n";
//output   18-09-26 03:05:00.
```

Comment: You want get current time +03:05

Answer (score 0):

Date objects don't really work that way.  They're just for storing time values, they're not a clock.  You're going to have to get the time at start via something like `$start = time();`.  From there whenever you want to find out the elapsed time you could do a `$elapsed = time() - $start;` to get the number of seconds that have passed since the script started and then you're free to do the math from there or do something akin to `$date->add($elapsed . ' seconds');`

Comment: how do i set clock at  3:05

Comment: There is no "clock" in php.  The PHP date object only handles date/times as a `data type`. This is useful because the math for dates is *weird* compared to normal math.  Case in point; `5 + 10 = 15`  HOWEVER `5pm + 10 Hours = 3am the next day`.  The date object automates this sort of funky math for you, however it is *not* a clock.  You can access the system's clock at anytime however, and do math to adjust the time based off the system's clock however you want.